# eclipse error: object references an unsaved transient instance before flushing: com.model.um.Designation javax. #{memoMB.onBtnCreate}:

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I am working on Eclipse JAVA and I am using JSF, hibernate and primefaces along with an mvc framework.

When I call the create function it displays an error "object references an unsaved transient instance  before flushing: com.model.um.Designation javax.faces.FacesException"

CODE:

```
"xhtml file"
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >

<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/pages/protected/templates/master.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="divMain">
            <h:form id="idMemoCreateForm">
                <p:panel id="toggleable" header="Create/Update Memo" toggleable="true" closable="false" toggleSpeed="500" closeSpeed="500" widgetVar="panel" style="margin-bottom:20px">

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">


                         <h:outputText for ="subject1" value="#{bundle.subject}" />
                        <p:inputText id ="subject1" value="#{memoMB.newMemo.subject}" required="true" label="#{bundle.subject}" >
                        </p:inputText>

                        <h:outputText value="Priority" />
                    <p:selectOneRadio id="priority" value="#{memoMB.newMemo.memoSubject}">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Normal" itemValue="Normal" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="High" itemValue="High" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Medium" itemValue="Medium" />
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Low" itemValue="Low" />
                    </p:selectOneRadio>

                        <h:outputLabel for="descript" value="Memorandum Body"/>
               <p:inputTextarea id="descript" value="#{memoMB.newMemo.memoBody}" rows="5" cols="30" counter="display3" maxlength="100" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." autoResize="false" />
                 <h:outputText id="display3" /> 
                        <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.create}" icon="ui-icon-plus"
                            action="#{memoMB.onBtnCreate}" update="messages"/>



                        <p:commandButton immediate="true" ajax="false" action="#{personMB.onBtnCancel}" value="#{bundle.cancel}"/>


                        <p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" /> 
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>    
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>


@entity
"Bean File"


@ManagedBean(name="memoMB")
@SessionScoped

public class MemoMB extends BaseMB implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5058440015517299917L;
    public static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(MemoMB.class.getName());

    private Memorandum selectedMemo;
    private Designation selectedDesign;
    private Designation selectedDesignation;
    private Memorandum newMemo;

    public MemoMB()
    {
        selectedDesign = new Designation();
        selectedDesignation = new Designation();
        selectedMemo = new Memorandum();
        newMemo = new Memorandum();
    }

    public Memorandum getNewMemo() {
        return newMemo;
    }

    public void setNewMemo(Memorandum newMemo) {
        this.newMemo = newMemo;
    }

    public Memorandum getSelectedMemo() {
        return selectedMemo;
    }

    public void setSelectedMemo(Memorandum selectedMemo) {
        this.selectedMemo = selectedMemo;
    }

    public Designation getSelectedDesign() {
        return selectedDesign;
    }

    public void setSelectedDesign(Designation selectedDesign) {
        this.selectedDesign = selectedDesign;
    }

    public Designation getSelecedDesignation() {
        return selectedDesignation;
    }

    public void setSelecedDesignation(Designation selecedDesignation) {
        this.selectedDesignation = selecedDesignation;
    }
    public String onBtnCreate()
    {

        newMemo.setDate(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        newMemo.setDesignation(selectedDesign);
        newMemo.setDesignation(selectedDesignation);

        controller.saveMemo(newMemo);
        System.out.println("Saved");
        displayInfoMessage("Memorandum saved/updated successfully");
        return "index.xhtml";

    }
}
```

Can you help me on what is causing the error?

Comment: First of all you are replacing the Designation of your newMemo, you must delete the line `newMemo.setDesignation(selectedDesign);` because it has no effect. The error can be that in your mapping you don't let to create new objects on insert, can you post your mappings?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the anotation  `cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}` for the entity Person and the entity Designation, [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade) you have the Hibernate documentation

if you want to use the session.save(obj) method you may put the annotation

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
```

And if you want a cascade in all the operations your choice must be

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
```